# What is the easiest way to move to New York from the UK?

Tags: usa, working-visas, visa, h1-visa, uk-citizens

I am a UK citizen and I want to emigrate to New York. My grandma is a US citizen but is currently living in the UK. I'm not sure if that helps. And I work as a web developer which is supposedly a job which is wanted in the US so I could get a H1B visa. If that is the case then how do I go about finding an employer willing to employ me?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is on hold. What more information do you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### H1B Visa Caps

A few thoughts...  The US has a [FY2014 H1B Visa Cap](http://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/h-1b-specialty-occupations-and-fashion-models/h-1b-fiscal-year-fy-2014-cap-season), which may make it challenging for you to get something soon.  There are exceptions to that cap though...

> The H-1B visa has an annual numerical limit "cap" of 65,000 visas each fiscal year. The first 20,000 petitions filed on behalf of beneficiaries with a U.S. master’s degree or higher are exempt from the cap.  Additionally, H-1B workers who are petitioned for or employed at an institution of higher education or its affiliated or related nonprofit entities or a nonprofit research organization, or a government research organization are not subject to this numerical cap.

Filing for FY2015 H1B visas starts on 1 Apr 2014 (terrible choice for the date, IMHO ☺); and the first start date for FY2015 H1B employment is October 1, 2014.

#### Strategy

I think your best shot at getting a job in the US is sharing your resume with some US-based headhunters, and ask them to focus on:

- Companies willing to sponsor an H1B for their web developer position (these would be subject to the H1B visa cap)
- Universities (not subject to the cap)
- Government / Non-profit research corporations (not subject to the cap)

Just be aware that headhunters sometimes don't have your best interests in mind; although they will always say that they do.  The reality is they have mouths to feed, and they are [paid when they fill job requisitions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/17440/1243).  YMMV... feet first, etc...

#### H1B Alternative

Apply to be a university grad student in the US, and work part-time until you find something full-time (after your school is finished).